# Google chat API - Receive user reaction on bot message

Tags: google-chat

I'm wondering if the Google Chat API can call our endpoint when a user put a reaction (an emoji) on the message

has anyone made this working ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Issue:

You want the bot to be notified when there's a reaction to a message.

This functionality is currently not available, since the only Chat events that may trigger an action are:

- `ADDED_TO_SPACE`: bot is added to a room or DM.
- `REMOVED_FROM_SPACE`: bot is removed from a room or DM.
- `MESSAGE`: a message has been sent to the bot.

#### Feature request:

This feature has been requested before in Issue Tracker, see:

- [Allow bots to be notified on emotes](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/128981860)

I'd suggest you to star this FR, in order to keep track of it and to help prioritizing it. Also, since this FR has not been getting much traction, I'd consider creating a new one in the [Chat API component](https://issuetracker.google.com/components/350158/manage#basic), explaining the potential usefulness of this functionality.

#### Reference:

- [Chat API: Event types](https://developers.google.com/hangouts/chat/reference/message-formats/events#event_types)